# Regex to get matches inside group

Tags: regex, preg-match

I don't know if the following is possibile.
Let's suppose I have the following text:

```
<ul class="yes">
    <li><img src="whatever1"></li>
    <li><img src="whatever2"></li>
    <li><img src="whatever3"></li>
    <li><img src="whatever4"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="no">
    <li><img src="whatever5"></li>
    <li><img src="whatever6"></li>
    <li><img src="whatever7"></li>
    <li><img src="whatever8"></li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to match every img's src inside the ul with class yes.
I want one regex returning me:

```
whatever1
whatever2
whatever3
whatever4
```

How can I join two regex like these in one regex?

```
<ul class="yes">(.+?)<\/ul>
<img src="(whatever.+?)">
```

Comment: why `whatever5` ,`whatever6` are not a match?

Comment: because they're inside ul with class no.

Comment: @Braj: he's written `in class=yes`

Comment: yes I got the point later.

Comment: you'd better specify a reason whenever downvoting!

Comment: from whose is your last comment?

Comment: for anyone who downvoted the question, it was -1 a while ago. It's a bad habit now living here: without pointing any reason is not constructive a downvote.

Comment: Using RegEx to process HTML is rarely a good idea.  @famousgarkin's HTML processor approach is how I would handle your use case.

Comment: its not just for html processing. what about a common txt? or whenever you cannot have a dom/document-logic parser?

Answer (score 1):

Regex is well known to be hard to use for parsing XML-like stuff. Better skip the idea and roll with a proper HTML parser instead, e.g. using [BeautifulSoup4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
import bs4

html = """
<ul class="yes">
    <li><img src="whatever1"></li>
    <li><img src="whatever2"></li>
    <li><img src="whatever3"></li>
    <li><img src="whatever4"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="no">
    <li><img src="whatever5"></li>
    <li><img src="whatever6"></li>
    <li><img src="whatever7"></li>
    <li><img src="whatever8"></li>
</ul>
"""

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)

def match_imgs(tag):
    return tag.name == 'img' \
        and tag.parent.parent.name == 'ul' \
        and tag.parent.parent['class'] == ['yes']

imgs = soup.find_all(match_imgs)
print(imgs)

whatevers = [i['src'] for i in imgs]
print(whatevers)
```

Yields:

```
[<img src="whatever1"/>, <img src="whatever2"/>, <img src="whatever3"/>,
<img src="whatever4"/>]

[u'whatever1', u'whatever2', u'whatever3', u'whatever4']
```

Comment: thanks famousgarkin but it's not just about html processing. it is more referred to regex and that kind of necessity.

Comment: @DamianoBarbati Okay, in that case I'm just pointing out. Will leave it here as an alternative.